# MYSQL - Get course name of course given by teacher 1 and 2

Tags: mysql

If you had the following tables:

```
   course:
   +---------------+---------------+
   |      id       |     Name      |
   |---------------|---------------| 
   |      1        |   Maths       | 
   |      2        |   English     |        
   |      3        |   Art         |        
   |      4        |   Physics     |        
   |      5        |   Psychology  |        
   +-------------------------------+        

   course_teacher:                                   
   +----------------------+---------------------+        
   |      course_id       |     teacher_id      |
   |----------------------|---------------------|
   |      1               |   1                 |
   |      2               |   1                 |
   |      1               |   2                 |
   |      2               |   2                 |
   |      3               |   2                 |
   +----------------------v---------------------+
```

How can I get a list of courses names given by teacher 1 and 2.

What I tried: `SELECT DISTINCT(`course_id`) FROM`course_teacher`WHERE`teacher_id`IN (1,2);`

However that query filters all the double results it does not filter on teacher 1 AND 2.

Comment: for basic "join cheatsheet", I can't recommend this enough: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(name) FROM courses c
INNER JOIN course_teachers ct ON c.id = ct.course_id 
WHERE ct.teacher_id = 1 OR ct.teacher_id = 2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f7f9/6/0

If you want only courses for both of teachers, then it's relevant:

```
SELECT name FROM courses c
INNER JOIN course_teachers ct ON c.id = ct.course_id 
WHERE ct.teacher_id = 1 OR ct.teacher_id = 2 GROUP BY c.id 
HAVING COUNT(c.id) = 2;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8f7f9/7/0

Comment: Ok I already found a solution but yours looks better anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Found it I now `JOIN` the table:

```
SELECT vk1.`course_id` 
FROM `course_teacher` vk1, `course_teacher` vk2
WHERE vk1.`teacher_id` =2
AND vk2.`teacher_id` =10
AND vk1.`course_id` = vk2.`course_id` 
GROUP BY vk1.`course_id`
```

*Note that I did not include the course name! That requires an extra `JOIN`*